# How to combine rows with the same ID into a list

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

How can I make the below table like a list.

```
Id   Name
1    Tim
1    George
2    Rachael
3    Mark
3    Blake
```

I want the result to be like this

```
Id    Name
1     Tim,George
2     Rachael
3     Mark,Blake
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, can you confirm that the patern is to group names every two rows? Can you provide more information?

Comment: Are you looking for a DAX measure for a visual or an M solution in the query editor or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following, it may solve your problem.

Let's say your existing table name is `yourTable` and the new table to be created  is `groupedNames`. in data view, click on new table and paste the following:

```
groupedNames = calculatetable
(
    addcolumns(
        summarize(yourTable ,yourTable[Id ]),
        "Names",calculate(CONCATENATEX(yourTable,[ Name ],","))
    )   
)
```

Answer (score 7):

This can be done in a single step by replacing an existing aggregate function in a Group By with `Text.Combine`.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUQrJzFWK1YGw3VPzi9JTwVwjIDcoMTkjMTUHzDcG8n0Ti7LhHKecxGyg0lgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Id = _t, Name = _t]),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Id"}, {{"Names", each Text.Combine([Name],","), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

To get this, I used the GUI to group on the `Id` column and told it to take the max of the `Name` column for my new `Names` aggregated column.

[image: Group By]

This generates the step

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Id"}, {{"Names", each List.Max([Name]), type text}})
```

and all you need to do is swap out `List.Max` for `Text.Combine`.

Comment: Hey Alexis, I was going to reduce my solution, but I thought I'd stick with what I achieved from the toolbar. If I was to continue, I would do it the way you have, I knew there was a one-line solution there!

Answer (score 1):

I like the DAX answer, this is the Power Query solution, slightly more longwinded, but I did it all from the toolbar. If you paste it in you can see the steps neatly

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUQrJzFWK1YGw3VPzi9JTwVwjIDcoMTkjNQfMNQZyfROLsuEcp5zEbKDKWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Id = _t, Name = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Id", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Id"}, {{"allNames", each _, type table [Id=number, Name=text]}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each [allNames][Name]),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"allNames"}) 
in
#"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried that solution and here's my version of that but with more than 2 columns.

```
 #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Pivoted Column", {"id", "primaryEmailAddress", "identifier", "fullName", "employerName", "employerIdentifier", "city", "stateProvince", "postalCode", "country", "role.id", "role.name", "type.id", "type.name",
                                                      "isDeleted", "lastMeeting", "emptyCustomField", "CS1", "CS2"}, {{"alternativeEmailAddresses.id", each Text.Combine([alternativeEmailAddresses.id],", "), type nullable text}, {"alternativeEmailAddresses.address", 
                                                      each Text.Combine([alternativeEmailAddresses.emailAddress],","), type nullable text}}),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).