# PowerQuery/M: How can I combine text from multiple rows into one row

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a table in PowerQuery like this:

| # | KeyA | KeyB | Comment | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | A1 | B1 | Comment 1 | 1 |
| 2. | A1 | B1 | Comment 2 | 3 |
| 3. | A2 | B2 | Comment 3 | 6 |

How can I combine it so that rows with the same entries in columns `KeyA` and `KeyB` (e.g. #1 & #2 in the example) concat the text in column `Comment` and sum the value in column `Value`, i.e. resulting in this:

| A | B | Comments | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | Comment 1, Comment 2 | 4 |
| A2 | B2 | Comment 3 | 6 |

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238999

Answer (score 2):

`Table.Group` is doing exactly what is required!

Here's the solution to the problem:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [KeyA="A1", KeyB="B1", Comment="Comment 1", Value=1], 
        [KeyA="A1", KeyB="B1", Comment="Comment 2", Value=2], 
        [KeyA="A2", KeyB="B2", Comment="...", Value=3]
     }),
    Grouped = Table.Group(
        Source,
        {"KeyA", "KeyB"},
        {
            {"Comments", (t) => Text.Combine(t[Comment], ", ")}, // <- Magic happens here!
            {"Sum", (t) => List.Sum(t[Value])},
            {"RecordCount", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}
        }
    )
in
    Grouped
```

### Explanation:

The function requires 3 parameters:

1. the source data
2. a list of columns that should be used for grouping
3. a list of function that produce the new aggregated column(s)

The last parameter is the key and where the functions power comes in: internally PowerQuery calls each of these function provided with a table as parameter that contains all the rows for one group. What you do with it, is completely up to you, i.e. you can aggregate it using List.Sum, Avg, ... - but you can also do any other modification of the table.

The entry `{"Comments", (t) => Text.Combine(t[Comment], ", ")}` creates a new column `Comments`. `(t) => ...` is the function defition. This function get called for each group - with a table containing all rows of this group. `t[Comment]` extracts the `Comment` column from the table as a list - which can then be used with the `List.Combine` function to concatenate.

### How to get started from the PowerQuery editor

If you have the Source table in the PowerQuery editor, select column `KeyA` and `KeyB` and click *Group By* in the *Transform* ribbon. This will scaffold the `Table.Group` query with a record count. USe the Advanced Editor for further modifications.

[image: Screenshot from PowerQuery editor]

Comment: Excellent explanation of GroupBy. Is it more efficient (executes more quickly), with complex aggregations, to do this within the GroupBy function, or to GroupBy "all rows" and then add custom columns.  *In VBA I can use a hi-res timer to compare different ways of doing things.*

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - so you mean to only add one column that contains all rows per group in the `Table.Group` function - and then do the other aggregations as individual next steps? I have not measured it, but intuitively I would expect that doing it all in the `Group` function should be more efficient...

Comment: Doing it within the `Group` function is certainly neater programming. But the other way, for **aggregations that are not built-in** to the UI, was the method I first came across when trying to learn to use PQ.  But I don't know what goes on behind the scenes, as the code gets compiled, nor do I know of any way to measure execution times for these sorts of things.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Regarding performance measurement: For PowerBI, check out http://blog.binaryrepublik.com/2020/02/measure-power-query-performance-using.html
For Excel you can use your VBA approach and refresh the connection - might have to do this multiple times during one measurement depending on run-time of the query. Just make sure that the "Background refresh" of the connection is disabled (it is on by default)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.